# AutoCompleteStringCollection with tags for each string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to give an string entry in an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` an additional `Tag`? Cause there is no native way that I found in my research, I tried to implement it by myself. But now the issue is, that it doesn't seem to fire an additional event when the user clicked on an entry in the `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, lets say for example in a `TextBox`.

1. Is it possible to do this natively?
2. If not, how can I know what index the user clicked on so I can tell whether input was typed manually (`TextChanged`-Event) or by selection (??-event)?

Comment: You can check if its an element of the collection by `if (AutoComplStrCol.Contains(TextBox1.Text))`

Comment: Yeah, I do this already. But it seems to be a bad solution, because its 1. slow and 2. this does not guarantee correct function when there are two same strings in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seems to be no alternative solution, I've implemented my own.
Use this if you want. You can use the `TextChanged`-Event of `TextBox` or `ComboBox` to grab the values using the `GetTag` extension method.

```
public class TaggedAutoCompleteStringCollection : AutoCompleteStringCollection
{
    private List<object> _tags;

    public TaggedAutoCompleteStringCollection()
        : base()
    {
        _tags = new List<object>();
    }

    public int Add(string value, object tag)
    {
        int result = this.Add(value);
        _tags.Add(tag);

        return result;
    }

    public void AddRange(string[] value, object[] tag)
    {
        base.AddRange(value);
        _tags.AddRange(tag);
    }

    public new void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        _tags.Clear();
    }

    public bool ContainsTag(object tag)
    {
        return _tags.Contains(tag);
    }

    public int IndexOfTag(object tag)
    {
        return _tags.IndexOf(tag);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, string value, object tag)
    {
        base.Insert(index, value);
        _tags.Insert(index, tag);
    }

    public new void Remove(string value)
    {
        int index = this.IndexOf(value);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            base.RemoveAt(index);
            _tags.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }

    public new void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        base.RemoveAt(index);
        _tags.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public object TagOfString(string value)
    {
        int index = base.IndexOf(value);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return _tags[index];
    }
}

public static class TaggedAutoCompleteStringCollectionHelper
{
    public static object GetTag(this TextBox control)
    {
        var source = control.AutoCompleteCustomSource as TaggedAutoCompleteStringCollection;

        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return source.TagOfString(control.Text);
    }

    public static object GetTag(this ComboBox control)
    {
        var source = control.DataSource as TaggedAutoCompleteStringCollection;

        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return source.TagOfString(control.Text);
    }
}
```